# Remote device not accessible from VPN even if under the same subnet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, subnet, fritzbox

I set up a point-to-point [tunnel VPN using a FritzBox](https://en.avm.de/service/vpn/tips-tricks/setting-up-a-vpn-connection-to-fritzbox-in-linux/) between my network and a remote machine. My goal is to reach the remote devices like they are inside my local network.

Here the network configuration seen from the remote device:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:18:05:87:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.14/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 57552sec preferred_lft 57552sec
    inet6 fe80::230:18ff:fe05:8736/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:18:05:87:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:66:55:c2:f5:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1412 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.1.201/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e28d:d83b:8dc:fe01/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and here from the local machine:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:89:a5:c1:d2:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.26/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft 862067sec preferred_lft 862067sec
    inet6 fe80::8e89:a5ff:fec1:d2cd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:70:02:a0:fd:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ztmjfge2h7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2800 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:5c:ee:ca:9c:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.107.117/16 brd 172.22.255.255 scope global ztmjfge2h7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5c50:83ff:fe2b:44ea/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see:

REMOTE MACHINE:

```
enp2s0 192.168.0.14/16
tun0   192.168.1.201/24
```

LOCAL MACHINE:

```
enp4s0 192.168.1.26/16
```

If I disable the VPN, from the remote machine I can reach any device under 192.168.1.x.
But when the VPN is enabled, I can't.

Instead, any machine under 192.168.0.x is reachable even if the VPN is active.

I'm afraid the problem is the `/24` netmask for `tun0`. Unfortunately, the manufacturer of FritzBox says it's hardcoded in the firmware and I cannot change it...

Is there any configuration I can do on the remote or local machine in order to by-pass this limitation?

Comment: In a VPN setup, the subnet of one end must be different from the subnet of the other end. You have made everything 192.168.1  at each end from what I can see above so the VPN is confused. Make the subnets different.

Comment: @John, the short answer is I can't. Because on my side the subnet is hardcoded in the FritzBox (the developer said this) and on the remote side the configuration is made by their IT department and of course they cannot change the whole setup for me.

Comment: Two ends on same subnet won't work through VPN.

Comment: I tried to change my ipv4 settings on my side so the router address and the DHCP range are under 192.168.2.x, but still the FritzBox assigns address under 192.168.1.x for VPN devices.